# Can not build Moveit

Tags: moveit, ros-humble, build, colcon, moveit-setup-assistant

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and ROS2 Humble. I am trying to build Moveit for some robotic applications but I could not do colcon build the tutorials. I tried to do the Moveit tutorials. I got some errors while building. How can I fix them? What should I do? Has anyone solved this problem before? Here are the errors:

````
--- stderr: moveit_setup_srdf_plugins
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit2/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_srdf_plugins/include/moveit_setup_srdf_plugins/rotated_header_view.hpp:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
---
Finished <<< moveit_setup_srdf_plugins [1min 40s]

--- stderr: moveit_visual_tools
In file included from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/logging.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/client.hpp:40,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/any_executable.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategy.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor_options.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor.hpp:37,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.h:48,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/buffer.h:42,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.hpp:42,
                 from /home/eser/ws_moveit/src/moveit_visual_tools/src/imarker_end_effector.cpp:41:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_visual_tools/src/imarker_end_effector.cpp: In function ‘bool {anonymous}::isStateValid(const planning_scene::PlanningScene*, bool, bool, const MoveItVisualToolsPtr&, moveit::core::RobotState*, const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*, const double*)’:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_visual_tools/src/imarker_end_effector.cpp:101:46: warning: use of old-style cast to ‘rcutils_duration_value_t’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wold-style-cast]
  101 |   RCLCPP_WARN_THROTTLE(LOGGER, steady_clock, 2000, "Collision");
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/logging.hpp:24,
                 from/home/ws_moveit/install/moveit_core/include/moveit_core/moveit/kinematics_base/kinematics_base.h:42,
                 from /home/ws_moveit/install/moveit_core/include/moveit_core/moveit/robot_model/joint_model_group.h:42,
                 from /home/ws_moveit/install/moveit_core/include/moveit_core/moveit/robot_model/robot_model.h:45,
                 from /home/ws_moveit/install/moveit_core/include/moveit_core/moveit/robot_state/robot_state.h:40,
                 from /home/ws_moveit/install/moveit_core/include/moveit_core/moveit/robot_state/conversions.h:39,
                 from /home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_visual_tools/src/imarker_robot_state.cpp:34:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_visual_tools/src/imarker_robot_state.cpp: In function ‘bool {anonymous}::isIKStateValid(const planning_scene::PlanningScene*, bool, bool, const MoveItVisualToolsPtr&, moveit::core::RobotState*, const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*, const double*)’:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_visual_tools/src/imarker_robot_state.cpp:101:48: warning: use of old-style cast to ‘rcutils_duration_value_t’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wold-style-cast]
  101 |     RCLCPP_WARN_THROTTLE(LOGGER, steady_clock, 2000, "Collision in IK CC callback");
      |                                                ^~~~
--- stderr: moveit_py
lto-wrapper: warning: using serial compilation of 9 LTRANS jobs
/usr/include/pybind11/stl.h:172:49: note: type ‘struct type_caster’ itself violates the C++ One Definition Rule
  172 | template <typename Type, typename Alloc> struct type_caster<std::vector<Type, Alloc>>
      |                                                 ^
/usr/include/pybind11/cast.h:33:56: note: the incompatible type is defined here
   33 | template <typename type, typename SFINAE = void> class type_caster : public type_caster_base<type> { };
      |                                                        ^
lto-wrapper: warning: using serial compilation of 7 LTRANS jobs


--- stderr: moveit_task_constructor_core
In file included from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/logging.hpp:24,
                 from /home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/core/src/properties.cpp:42:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/core/src/properties.cpp: In member function ‘const moveit::task_constructor::PropertyTypeRegistry::Entry& moveit::task_constructor::PropertyTypeRegistry::entry(const std::type_index&) const’:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/core/src/properties.cpp:78:75: warning: use of old-style cast to ‘rcutils_duration_value_t’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wold-style-cast]
   78 |                         RCLCPP_WARN_STREAM_THROTTLE(LOGGER, steady_clock, 10'000,
      |                                                                           ^~~~~~
---

--- stderr: moveit_task_constructor_capabilities
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp: In member function ‘bool move_group::ExecuteTaskSolutionCapability::constructMotionPlan(const Solution&, plan_execution::ExecutableMotionPlan&)’:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:155:14: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableMotionPlan’ has no member named ‘plan_components’; did you mean ‘plan_components_’?
  155 |         plan.plan_components.reserve(solution.sub_trajectory.size());
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              plan_components_
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:158:22: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableMotionPlan’ has no member named ‘plan_components’; did you mean ‘plan_components_’?
  158 |                 plan.plan_components.emplace_back();
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                      plan_components_
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:159:72: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableMotionPlan’ has no member named ‘plan_components’; did you mean ‘plan_components_’?
  159 |                 plan_execution::ExecutableTrajectory& exec_traj = plan.plan_components.back();
      |                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                        plan_components_
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:162:27: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableTrajectory’ has no member named ‘description’; did you mean ‘description_’?
  162 |                 exec_traj.description = std::to_string(i + 1) + "/" + std::to_string(solution.sub_trajectory.size());
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                           description_
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:179:27: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableTrajectory’ has no member named ‘trajectory’; did you mean ‘trajectory_’?
  179 |                 exec_traj.trajectory = std::make_shared<robot_trajectory::RobotTrajectory>(model, group);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                           trajectory_
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:180:27: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableTrajectory’ has no member named ‘trajectory’; did you mean ‘trajectory_’?
  180 |                 exec_traj.trajectory->setRobotTrajectoryMsg(state, sub_traj.trajectory);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                           trajectory_
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:188:27: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableTrajectory’ has no member named ‘controller_name’; did you mean ‘controller_names_’?
  188 |                 exec_traj.controller_name = sub_traj.execution_info.controller_names;
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                           controller_names_
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:191:27: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableTrajectory’ has no member named ‘effect_on_success’; did you mean ‘effect_on_success_’?
  191 |                 exec_traj.effect_on_success =
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                           effect_on_success_
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:192:62: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableTrajectory’ has no member named ‘description’; did you mean ‘description_’?
  192 |                     [this, sub_traj, description = exec_traj.description](const plan_execution::ExecutableMotionPlan* /*plan*/) {
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                              description_
In file included from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/client.hpp:40,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/any_executable.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategy.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor_options.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor.hpp:37,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/moveit/planning_scene_monitor/planning_scene_monitor.h:39,
                 from /home/ws_moveit/install/moveit_ros_move_group/include/moveit_ros_move_group/moveit/move_group/move_group_capability.h:40,
                 from/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.h:44,
                from/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:37:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp: In lambda function:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:194:87: error: ‘description’ was not declared in this scope
  194 |                                     RCLCPP_DEBUG_STREAM(LOGGER, "apply effect of " << description);
      |                                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp: In member function ‘bool move_group::ExecuteTaskSolutionCapability::constructMotionPlan(const Solution&, plan_execution::ExecutableMotionPlan&)’:
/home/ws_moveit/src/moveit_task_constructor/capabilities/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp:203:70: error: ‘struct plan_execution::ExecutableTrajectory’ has no member named ‘description’; did you mean ‘description_’?
  203 |                                                         << exec_traj.description);
      |                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/moveit_task_constructor_capabilities.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/moveit_task_constructor_capabilities.dir/src/execute_task_solution_capability.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/moveit_task_constructor_capabilities.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---

Failed   <<< moveit_task_constructor_capabilities [19.2s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 56 packages finished [57min 24s]
  1 package failed: moveit_task_constructor_capabilities
  5 packages had stderr output: moveit_py moveit_setup_srdf_plugins moveit_task_constructor_capabilities moveit_task_constructor_core moveit_visual_tools
  13 packages not processed
```
````

Comment: Did you checkout the correct branch? Make sure it is the humble branch

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you run this [tutorial](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html) step-by-step?

I mean maybe you could have forgotten to run this rosdep cmd line ?

```
sudo apt update && rosdep install -r --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y
```

This command will install all ROS2 dependencies which MoveIt pkgs require.

I have reproduced this tutorial for my ROS2 Iron and compiled successfully all the MoveIt packages.

[image]

My computer has 16 GB RAM if you read the tutorial you will check that if your PC does not have this amount of resources, you will need to issue other cmd to compile your workspace

[image]

It is also possible compile package by package using:

```
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select name_of_package
```